# Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey sript to click button

Tags: button, click, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have this website that I would like to click the "Log In" button.
https://www.paycomonline.net/v4/ee/web.php/app/login

I have played around with a few functions with no success (I am not a web coder / programmer).

The line that creates the button is: 
    `<button type="submit" name="submit" id="btnSubmit" class=" waves-effect waves-light" aria-label="Log In">Log In</button>`

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance!

The full code for the form is:

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" >
 <div class="cardContainer shadow padding marginBottom formGroup row">
  <div class="row formRowStandard ">
   <label class="standard" for="txtlogin"><span class="required">*</span>Username</label>
    <div class="formLine">
     <div class="formControl fbControl">
      <input type="text" name="username" type="text" name="username" id="txtlogin" size="25" maxlength="75" placeholder="Username" class=" inputBoxBorder" aria-label="Username" required="required" value="">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row formRowStandard ">
    <label class="standard" for="txtpass"><span class="required">*</span>Password</label>
     <div class="formLine">
      <div class="formControl fbControl"><input type="password" name="userpass" type="password" name="userpass" id="txtpass" size="25" maxlength="20" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" class=" checkForCapslock inputBoxBorder" aria-label="Password" required="required" value="">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row formRowStandard "><label class="standard" for="userpinid"><span class="required">*</span>Last 4 digits of SSN</label>
    <div class="formLine">
     <div class="formControl fbControl"><input type="password" name="userpin" type="password" name="userpin" id="userpinid" size="25" maxlength="4" placeholder="Last 4 digits of SSN" class=" inputBoxBorder" aria-label="Last 4 digits of SSN" required="required" value="">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row formRowStandard ">
   <div class="formLine">
    <div ><button type="submit" name="submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="btnSubmit" class=" waves-effect waves-light" aria-label="Log In">Log In</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried before asking on SO? Can you please post your code. Remember this, Stackoverflow is not a coding service. Unless you post some code, don't aspect an answer

Comment: I have tried to use:
'unsafeWindow.$("submit").click();'
As well as changing 'submit' to 'Log In' and 'btnSubmit' and none of those worked either.

Answer (score -1):

Actually got this to work with:

```
document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
```